# Почему WordPress отображает Woocommerce страницы пустыми?

Tags: woocommerce

Привет создал новую чистую тему. Установил WooCommerce. Если ставлю страницы WooCommerce( Магазин ) к примеру как главная страница. Это просто пустая страница. Создал папку WOoCommerce куда ставлял файлы, к примеру single-product.php - к сожалению без изменений - белая страница. Ошибку не выдаает, открывает, в title page идет названия страницы loc/product/nazvanya-producta

Comment: Тему создали неправильно. Наверняка wp_head() а ней не вызывается, или какая-то подобная ошибка. Никогда не начинайте знакомство с WordPress с создания своей темы, я устал уже это повторять.

Comment: надо было добавить поддержку темы WP

Comment: Я ровно о том и сказал - неправильно создана тема.